# How use table in other database for "through" kohana ORM?

Tags: mysql, orm, kohana-3.3

Sorry for my english, I'm from Ukraine.
I have next model

```
 class Model_Search extends ORM
    {
        protected $_has_many = array(
           'mp3s'       => array(
                        'model' => 'Mp3',
                        'through' => 'searches_mp3s',

                        ),
            );
```

but table searches_mp3s in other database, for example 'db2'. How I can do relationship with through for my situation? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In pure SQL this should be `database.table.field`. And you must have user-connection who allow read from both databases.

I don't know, that kohana understand `database.table` notation... 
You can try in your Model (ORM) class:

```
class Model_Search extends ORM
{
    protected  $_table_name = 'db1.search';
    protected $_has_many = array(
       'mp3s'       => array(
                    'model' => 'Mp3',
                    'through' => 'db2.searches_mp3s',

                    ),
        );
```